# How to append/replace an item from multi dimensional array by an item from another multi-dimensional array based on a specific condition

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, nested

I have 2 3-d arrays and am trying to replace the innermost element of 1st with the elements of 2nd array. The code I wrote is -

```
my_list = [
           [['K', ['a', 'i'], '1'], ['W', ['b', 'y'], '1']], 
           [['T ', ['d', 'i', 'e', 'q', 'f', 'j'], '1'], ['P', ['d', 'r'], '1']]]

ref_list =  [['a', ['M', 'H'], 'b', ['L', 'M']], ['e', ['F'], 'd', ['M', 'N']]]
for a, b in zip(my_list , ref_list ):
    for i, subl in enumerate(a):
        for ii, v in enumerate(subl):
            if isinstance(v, list):
                new_subl=subl[ii]
                subl[ii]=[]
                for j in b[i]:
                    subl[ii] +=[j] + new_subl
                break
```

I am not getting the desired output. The output I am looking for is of sort (expected output)-

```
[[['K', ['M', 'i', 'H', 'i'], '1'], ['W', ['L', 'y', 'M', 'y'], '1']], [['T ', ['M', 'i', 'N', 'i', 'F', 'q', 'f', 'j'], '1'], ['P', ['M', 'r', 'N', 'r'], '1']]]
```

I want to replace the innermost element of `my_list` with the elements of the innermost list of `ref_list` if that element exists in `ref_list`. As a refrence, I want to replace `['a', 'i']` with `['M', 'i', 'H', 'i']` as they are followed by `a` in `['a', ['M', 'H']` and so on for the rest of the elements. Also if the element is not found in `ref_list`, I don't want to touch it. For eg - `'f'` doesn't exist in `ref_list` so don't do anything with it.

Comment: @le123 it's in the question. I have added it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` with `collections.deque` to track the replacements as you iterate over the innermost lists of `my_list`:

```
from collections import deque
def update(a, b):
   d = {b[i]:b[i+1] for i in range(0, len(b), 2)}
   for x, y, z in a:
      g, r = [], deque()
      for i in y[::-1]:
         if i not in d:
            r.appendleft(i)
         else:
            g = [l for k in d[i] for l in [k, *r]]+g
            r = deque()
      g = list(r)+g
      yield [x, list(g), z]

my_list = [[['K', ['a', 'i'], '1'], ['W', ['b', 'y'], '1']], [['T ', ['d', 'i', 'e', 'q', 'f', 'j'], '1'], ['P', ['d', 'r'], '1']]]
ref_list = [['a', ['M', 'H'], 'b', ['L', 'M']], ['e', ['F'], 'd', ['M', 'N']]]
result = [list(update(*i)) for i in zip(my_list , ref_list)]
```

Output:

```
[[['K', ['M', 'i', 'H', 'i'], '1'], ['W', ['L', 'y', 'M', 'y'], '1']], [['T ', ['M', 'i', 'N', 'i', 'F', 'q', 'f', 'j'], '1'], ['P', ['M', 'r', 'N', 'r'], '1']]]
```